# Why does the square of a bivector give its magnitude squared?

Tags: abstract-algebra, exterior-algebra, geometric-algebras, outer-product

I'm trying to learn geometric algebra, but I've gotten stuck on the magnitude of a bivector. In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUivWb4k_bE) video, the following derivation is made:

For $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n, u^2v^2 = uv^2u = uvvu$

$= (u\cdot v + u \wedge v)(u\cdot v - u \wedge v)$

$=(u\cdot v)^2 - (u\wedge v)^2$

$= u^2 v^2 \cos^2(\theta_{uv}) - (u\wedge v)^2$

$\Rightarrow (u\wedge v)^2 = u^2v^2[\cos^2(\theta_{uv}) - 1] = -u^2v^2\sin^2(\theta_{uv})$

The author then concludes that $u\wedge v$ squares to a negative scalar, and as such is neither a scalar or a vector itself, but a new object (bivector). I understand that, but they then claim that the object $u\wedge v$ has the magnitude $|u||v|\sin(\theta_{uv})$. I understand that a bivector represents an oriented area, but I don't see how it follows that $(u\wedge v)^2 = |u\wedge v|^2$?

Wikipedia makes this claim as well [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector#The_exterior_product)

Any help much appreciated.

Edit:
I understand that the bivector squares to a real number with magnitude $|-u^2 v^2 \sin^2(\theta_{uv})|^2 = (|u||v|\sin(\theta_{uv}))^2$. I don't see how that means that the bivector itself has magnitude $|u\wedge v| = |u||v|\sin(\theta_{uv})$.

Answer (score 3):

I'm under the impression that you're perfectly OK with $(u\wedge v)^2=-u^2v^2\sin^2(\theta_{uv})$.

I don't think anyone's claiming that $(u\wedge v)^2=|u\wedge v|^2$.

Consider that $i^2=-1$, and we would say that $i^2$ has magnitude $1$ but we would not say that $i^2=|-1|^2$.

There are two things: the real number $(u\wedge v)^2$ and its magnitude squared $|u\wedge v|^2$.  It is not hard to compute $|-u^2v^2\sin^2(\theta_{uv})|^2=(|u||v|\sin(\theta_{uv}))^2$, and that quantity inside the square on the right is the familiar quantity that gives the magnitude of the cross product or, if you like, the volume of the spanned parallelpiped.

Are you perhaps thinking that every element of the geometric algebra squares to a positive number that is its magnitude?  It's important to remember that in the usual Euclidean signature geometric algebra, $v^2=|v|^2$ certainly for the *vectors* in $V$ but no such guarantee is made for the bivectors.  The magnitude defined for a bivector is related to but not the same thing as the original norm on $V$, which it extends.

Comment: Are you perfectly OK with$$(u\wedge v)^2=-u^2v^2\sin^2(\theta_{uv})$$too? I am irritated by the minus sign.

Comment: @Filippo I don't see anything wrong with it... it's no more strange than $i^2=-1$.

Comment: I understand that the bivector squares to a real number with magnitude $|-u^2 v^2 \sin^2(\theta_{uv})|^2 = (|u||v|\sin(\theta_{uv}))^2$, but I still dont see how that means that the bivector itself has magnitude $|u\wedge v| = |u||v|\sin(\theta_{uv})$.

Comment: Well, the inner product on the vector space in consideration induces an inner product on the vector space of bivectors and $$(u\wedge v)^2=u^2v^2\sin^2(\theta_{uv})$$where the LHS is the inner product of $u\wedge v$ with itself. So if we write$$(u\wedge v)^2=-u^2v^2\sin^2(\theta_{uv})$$the LHS is another kind of product?

Comment: @Filippo the LHS is the geometric product, not the inner product

Comment: @candr Is it not just a definition that we take the magnitude of a bivector to be this quantity, which is algebraically consistent with $\sqrt{|(u\wedge v)^2|}$, to be what we call the magnitude of a bivector?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, most authors just define $|u\wedge v|=|u||v|\sin(\theta)$ and move on. It just seems like the more axiomatic approaches (like wikipedia and the video) derive the magnitude of a bivector instead of defining it out of the blue. Maybe they just assume it though? idk.

Comment: @candr nothing they do “derives” that it is the magnitude. It just shows that algebraically it is a natural choice to pick, because it is familiar.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with your original expression  $u^{2} v^{2}=u v^{2} u=u v v u$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
u^{2} v^{2} &=(u \cdot v+u \wedge v)(v \cdot u+v \wedge u)=(u \cdot v+u \wedge u)(u \cdot v-u \wedge v) \\
u^{2}v^{2}&=(u \cdot v)^{2}-(u \wedge v)^{2} \\
u^{2} v^{2} &=u^{2} v^{2} \cos ^{2}(\theta)-(u \wedge v)^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Isolating $(u \wedge v)^{2}$

$$\begin{aligned}
u^{2} v^{2}\left(1-\cos ^{2} \theta\right)&=-(u \wedge v)^{2} \\
u^{2} v^{2} \sin ^{2} \theta&=-(u \wedge v)^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
we can see that the square of a bivector must be negative, as $u^{2}v^{2}\sin^{2}(\theta)$ is non-negative.

To calculate the magnitude of $u \wedge v$ it helps to remember the modulus of a complex number $|z| = \sqrt{zz^{*}}$.

$$
|u \wedge v|^{2}=-(u \wedge v)^{2}=(u \wedge v)(u \wedge v)^{\dagger}
$$
$$
|u \wedge v|=\sqrt{(u \wedge v)(v \wedge u)}=\sqrt{(u \wedge v) \cdot(v \wedge u)}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
=\sqrt{u \cdot(v \cdot(v \wedge u))} \\
=\sqrt{u \cdot((v \cdot v) u-v(v \cdot u))} \\
=\sqrt{v^{2} u^{2}-(u \cdot v)^{2}}\\
=|u||v|\sin(\theta)
\end{array}
$$