# A determinant invariant with respect to a change of metric (covariant determinant?)

Tags: matrices, vectors, determinant, covariance, gauge-theory

I use a multi-vector of G(2,R):

$$
\mathbf{u} = a+x\sigma_x+y \sigma_y + b \sigma_x\sigma_y
$$

its matrix representation is

$$
\mathbf{u} \cong \pmatrix{a +x & y-b \\y+b & a-x}
$$

and the determinant is $\det (\mathbf{u})=a^2-x^2-y^2+b^2$

I am now trying to create a "covariant" determinant.

I wish to transform the orthogonal basis to general curvilinear coordinates:

$$
\sigma_x \to e_0\\
\sigma_y \to e_1
$$

such that $e_\mu \cdot e_\nu = g_{\mu\nu}$.

If I do, however, the determinant is no longer equal to $a^2-x^2-y^2+b^2$, because the multi-vector is now $\mathbf{u} = a+xe_0+y e_1 + b e_0e_1$.

Is there a covariant definition of the determinant?

Comment: What do the sigmas represent? What is $G(2,R)$? And what is your definition of a multi-vector? I see no wedges...

Comment: @KevinS I believe he's talking about the geometric/Clifford algebra with signature ${+}{+}$ over the reals.

Comment: @Anon21 I don't understand what you want "covariant" to mean. Taking this sort of "covariance" that you're suggesting, not even the inner product is "covariant". The definition of determinant you have is already basis-independent, and depends only on the matrix representation you've chosen, and can be written $$\det\mathbf u=\langle\bar{\mathbf u}\mathbf u\rangle$$ where the bar is Clifford conjugation and the brackets are scalar projection.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Let's say I take G(1,R) (for simplicity), with $\mathbf{u}=a+be_0$. Then $\langle{\bar{\mathbf{u}},\mathbf{u}} \rangle= (a-be_0)(a+be_0) = a^2+b^2e_0e_0$. Then if is orthonormal $e_0e_0=1$, and if not $e_0e_0=g_{00}$. Hence, in this case it is not the same : $a^2+b^2$ vs $a^2+b^2g_{00}$ . I want $\langle{\bar{\mathbf{u}},\mathbf{u}} \rangle$ to always equal $a^2+b^2$, regardless of $g_{00}$.

Comment: That's not a well-defined function. $1+e_0$ maps to $2$ but $1+2(e_0/2)$ (the exact same thing in a different basis) maps to $5$.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff $(1-e_0)(1+e_0)=1-e_0^2$ and $(1-2(e_0/2))(1+2(e_0/2))=1-(2e_0/2)^2=1-e_0^2$. Same thing.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff - I think he just wants an expression for $\langle\overline{\mathbf u}\mathbf u\rangle$ in terms of a general non-orthogonal basis, but is not finding the right way to say so.

Comment: @mr_e_man yes! that is correct.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff - Never mind. It seems you were right, after all.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. Consider the $G(1,\mathbb R)$ case for simplicity. What you want is $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$ where $a + be_0 = c + de_0'$ for any two bases $e_0$ and $e_0'$. But take $a = b = 1$ and $e_0' = e_0/2$. Then $c = 1$ and $d = 2$, and then you're saying you want
$$
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2
$$$$
  1^2 + 1^2 = 1^2 + 2^2
$$$$
  2 = 5.
$$

In a covariant expression in Einstein notation like $a_ia^i$, we aren't just using the coordinates of a vector $a$, but also its *reciprocal* coordinates. This is *necessary* for forming covariant expression. Following the same idea, perhaps this is what you are looking for:

Let $\{e_i\}$ be an arbitrary curvilinear basis with $\{e^i\}$ its reciprocal basis, i.e. $e_i\cdot e^j = \delta_i^j$. Of course, $e^i = e_jg^{ji}$. Then in $G(4,\mathbb R)$
$$
  \mathbf u
= u + u^ie_i + \frac12u^{ij}e_i\wedge e_j
= u + u_ie^i + \frac12u_{ij}e^i\wedge e^j
$$
where $u_{ij}$ and $u^{ij}$ are antisymmetric. Then
$$
  \det\mathbf u
= \langle\bar{\mathbf u}\mathbf u\rangle
= \Bigl\langle(u - u^ie_i + \frac12u^{ij}e_i\wedge e_j)(u + u_ke^k + \frac12u_{kl}e^k\wedge e^l)\Bigr\rangle
$$$$
= uu - u^iu_ke_i\cdot e^k - \frac14u^{ij}u_{kl}(e_i\wedge e_j)\cdot(e^k\wedge e^l)
$$$$
= uu - u^iu_i - \frac14u^{ij}u_{kl}(\delta_j^k\delta_i^l - \delta_j^l\delta_i^k)
$$$$
= uu - u^iu_i - \frac14(u^{ij}u_{ji} - u^{ij}u_{ij})
$$$$
= uu - u^iu_i + \frac12u^{ij}u_{ij}.
$$
In the last line we've used $u_{ji} = -u_{ij}$. Note that this final expression also comes simply from writing $\langle\bar{\mathbf u}\mathbf u\rangle$ as squares of grade components and writing those in terms reciprocal coordinates.

All in all, I would prefer $\langle\bar{\mathbf u}\mathbf u\rangle$ as a "covariant" expression, since you can evaluate in any combination of bases you please, or in a coordinate-free manner.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbf u=\langle\mathbf u\rangle_0+\langle\mathbf u\rangle_1+\langle\mathbf u\rangle_2=a+xe_0+ye_1+b\,e_0\wedge e_1$$
$$\overline{\mathbf u}=\langle\mathbf u\rangle_0-\langle\mathbf u\rangle_1-\langle\mathbf u\rangle_2=a-xe_0-ye_1-b\,e_0\wedge e_1$$
$$\det\mathbf u=\langle\overline{\mathbf u}\mathbf u\rangle_0=\langle\mathbf u\rangle_0\!^2-\langle\mathbf u\rangle_1\!^2-\langle\mathbf u\rangle_2\!^2=a^2-(xe_0+ye_1)^2-(b\,e_0\wedge e_1)^2$$
$$=a^2-x^2e_0\!^2-xy(e_0e_1+e_1e_0)-y^2e_1\!^2-b^2((e_0e_1-e_1e_0)/2)^2$$
$$=a^2-x^2g_{00}-xy(2g_{01})-y^2g_{11}-b^2(g_{01}\!^2-g_{00}g_{11})$$

Comment: For the simplification of the last part, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420774/why-does-the-square-of-a-bivector-give-its-magnitude-squared), which shows that $(u\wedge v)^2=(u\cdot v)^2-u^2v^2$ (where the dot is the symmetrized product and the wedge is the antisymmetrized product), so $$(e_0\wedge e_1)^2=(e_0\cdot e_1)^2-e_0\!^2e_1\!^2=g_{01}\!^2-g_{00}g_{11}$$

Comment: Actually, what I am looking for is a definition of the determinant that gives $a^2+b^2$ for $a+be_0$, regardless of what $e_0e_0=g_{00}$ is. The determinant needs to be 'aware' of the metric.